# Read Attribute and create Text-Node with Renderer

Tags: angular

As directly accessing the DOM isn't recommended in Angular due to all the plattforms I wondering how to do something like this with the Renderer:

a) let left = $event.target.offsetLeft;
b) let textNode = document.createTextNode(this.message);

I looked at the documentation of the Renderer and did not find methods for this.

Is there an abstraction for this?

Wishes,
Manfred

Answer (score 0):

> As directly accessing the DOM isn't recommended in Angular due to all the plattforms

It is not recommended because of security reasons, you are more vulnerable to XSS attacks if you do that

[Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html) provides an API to create text via its `createText` function. It also has an API to create elements via `createElement`, each of these functions take the parent element as the first parameter to use as the immediate parent to the new element. `Renderer` also provides APIs to set the properties, and listeners via `setElementProperty` and`listen`. Check out the linked API doc for more info on `Renderer`